# WordPress Pages into Sections edit.php PHP hack

Tags: php, plugins

Im currently working on a Theme for a WordPress website. The theme affectively splits the website up into three sections.

```
http://url.com/section1  
http://url.com/section2  
http://url.com/section3
```

I need to be able to split up Pages in the backend into these sections. So in the menu it appears:

```
- Pages
    - Section 1
    - Section 2
    - Section 3
```

And when you go into the relevant section the "Add New Page" button would set the pages parent to be the corresponding section.

I realise this is very complicated,I currently have divided the menu but need to provide functions for each menu item.

Is there anyway to do this with action hooks? Or will I have to edit the core files new-post.php and edit.php?

Comment: What do you mean by "pages template" exactly? A page type? Pre-filled  HTML?

Comment: Sorry I updated this, I meant "page's parent". So that if you create a new page in Section 2 the page's parent would be Section 2 so that the url would be: http://url.com/section2/newpage

Comment: Mmm, isn't this covered by WP's standard functionality already? You can assign a parent to any page. You may have to activate the field in the options at the top of the screen

Comment: I need this to be done with PHP so that the user cannot set the Parent. And I need to know how to divide up the pages into the relevant sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need this to be done with PHP so that the user cannot set the Parent.

I asked this over on WP.SE and got a promising answer: [Creating new page with pre-defined parent page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44324/creating-new-page-with-pre-defined-parent-page) I haven't got around to testing it yet, though, as the project is on hold.

> And I need to know how to divide up the pages into the relevant sections.

I'm not sure what you mean by that and how deep a division you need in your project. To display the three sections, you could use [`wp_list_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) three times, and use the `child_of` parameter to pick the right section. Or you could have three menus in the backend, and call each of them using [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu).

Comment: I believe that answers my first question and I know that wp_list_pages() can be used. But I will need to display only the pages that are in section 1 with edit.php and in another case the pages that are in section 2 with edit.php. This diagram should help explain:
(Will update with diagram)

Comment: http://img547.imageshack.us/img547/4729/96056902.png

Comment: @ptimson I see. I imagine for that to happen, you'll have to dig deep into the code, no idea how feasible that is. One idea that comes to mind is misusing the [custom post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) concept - with those, you can get separate menu items in the back-end. But I don't know post types well enough to tell what other problems you'd probably encounter on your way.

Comment: Ok Ill leave this open for now then